# Facebook graph - value of 'people have been here'

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Sorry for the newbie question but ... can someone tell me how I find in the Graph the value for 'people have been here', for a Page for a specific place (e.g. a city)?

In the Graph explorer I see several values, but none of the values match or add-up to the 'people have been here' value.

For example one page I am looking at shows 421,711 people have been here.  In the Graph the values are:

"checkins": 3355

"talking_about_count": 9061

"were_here_count": 265150

"likes": 115313

Total: 392,879

Actually just noticed that the 'Likes' don't match either.  Is the Graph data an older version of the data?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The difference might come from users that have “opted out of the platform”, meaning they are not visible to apps _at all_.

Comment: It's very likely that you can't get this information via the API. Facebook doesn't let you have everything, and this looks like one of the features that they probably keep to themselves. It's fairly security sensitive... :(